# How to add a new Visual C# Project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How to add a new Visual C# Project (*.csproj) to an existing solution in Visual Studio 2013 as the ones shown in the picture below? (Northwind.Model, Northwind.Repositories and Northwind.Repositories.Entity):

[image]

Comment: Right click on the solution and select "New Project" (or the equivalent localization for you).

Comment: What type of project do I have to select? I do not see that rectangular icon with the string "C#" inside.